# Object type (This type is incompatible with undefined (too few arguments, expected default/rest parameters))

Tags: flowtype

I'm getting a flow error with the following code and I'm quite sure how to solve it. The error I'm getting is:

```
[flow] object type (This type is incompatible with undefined (too few arguments, expected default/rest parameters))
type Props = {
    levels: {
        image: string;
        name: string;
        description: string;
        slug: string;
        value: number;
    }[];
}
```

And here's my code:

```
// @flow
// @jsx h
import { h, Component } from 'preact';

// Components
import Level from '../components/Level';

type Props = {
  levels: Array<{
    image: string,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    slug: string,
    value: number,
  }>
};

type State = {}

class Levels extends Component<Props, State> {
  onclick = () => { /* ... */ }

  render({ levels }: Props) {
                     ^^^^^ <-- Error here
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {levels.map(level => <Level {...level} />)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Levels;
```

The error message is a little confusing because it says `incompatible with undefined`. I have defined the props though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Type-definitions for preact extend from react type definitions. Accessing props as `render` arguments is not supported on react, and flow assumes it to always be undefined. Consider accessing props as an instance property instead, like so: `this.props.levels.map(...)`. Both react and preact support this and it will keep flow happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed like so ...

```
class Levels extends Component<Props> {
  onclick = () => { /* ... */ }

  render(props: Props | void) {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {props && props.levels.map(level => <Level {...level} />)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The following page from the manual explains why: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-array-access-is-unsafe

I was unable to use: `render({ levels }: Props | void)` because flow complained that `levels` could be null. I found it easier to just use `props`.